# Why won't Helvetica Neue Bold glyphs draw as a normal subpath in NSBezierPath?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fonts, core-graphics, typography

What I want is to take a filled rectangle and punch a hole in it using another shape. This is exactly the kind of thing that `NSBezierPath` is designed for. You add a rectangular path, then add the subpath that will "punch" through it and finally fill it. In my case the subpath is actually text. No problem, works great:

[image]

Except when I use Helvetica Neue Bold for my font. When I use that, I just end up with a solid blue rectangle without any text at all. But the subpath is indeed drawing--in fact, if I shrink the filled rectangle a bit, you can actually see some of the text path:

[image]

I get the same behavior with Helvetica Neue Italic.  Helvetica Neue Medium works fine, as does Helvetica Bold, Times New Roman Bold and Arial Bold.

I've tried using both `NSEvenOddWindingRule` and `NSNonZeroWindingRule`. (**EDIT**: Apparently I didn't really try `NSEvenOddWinding` rule, because that does turn out to work after all)

This is the code that I'm using inside the `drawRect` method of my `NSView` subclass.

```
NSLayoutManager *layoutManger = [[[NSLayoutManager alloc] init] autorelease];
NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[[NSTextContainer alloc] 
      initWithContainerSize:NSMakeSize(300, 100)] autorelease];

NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:100];

NSDictionary *textAttribs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];

NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:@"Hello" 
                                        attributes:textAttribs] autorelease];

[layoutManger addTextContainer:textContainer];
[layoutManger setTextStorage:textStorage];

NSRange glyphRange = [layoutManger glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];

NSGlyph glyphArray[glyphRange.length];

NSUInteger glyphCount = [layoutManger getGlyphs:glyphArray range:glyphRange];

NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 100)];
[path appendBezierPathWithGlyphs:glyphArray count:glyphCount inFont:font];

[[NSColor blueColor] setFill];

[path fill];
```

So what's going on here? Why do some fonts behave differently than others when it comes to adding glyphs to a path?

**EDIT**: The solution is to use `NSEvenOddWindingRule`. After the creation of `path` add this line:

```
[path setWindingRule:NSEvenOddWindingRule];
```

Peter Hosey's answer provides the explanation of why this is.

Comment: I wonder if Helvetica Neue is a different type of font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably to do with the directions of the paths in the fonts. One font may use clockwise paths; another may use counterclockwise paths.

A more reliable way to achieve the effect you're after would be to simply fill the rectangle, and then draw the text out of it with the graphics context's compositing mode set to `NSCompositeSourceOut`. You can wrap the fill and text-draw in a transparency layer using Core Graphics if you want to cut the text only out of the fill.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. This solution works very well for my use case, even for Helvetica Neue Bold. I am still very curious as to why this actually happens though. Even within the same font there seem to be differences. Helvetica Neue and Helvetica Neue Bold both exhibit this confounding behavior, but Helvetica Neue Medium does not.  I am hoping that someone can actually explain why this is happening. I've gone through all of the text programming docs and was hoping that NSGlyphGenerator would give some more info, but no luck.

Comment: @Ben Dolman: The first paragraph in my answer explains the probable cause and why it's font-specific.

Comment: So Helvetica Neue and Helvetica Neue Medium draw in different directions? I know very little about glyph drawing, so it seems strange to me. Voodoo no me likey. Any ideas on where documentation for this behavior--or even a conceptual overview--exists? The Cocoa text programming docs don't seem to go this deep into glyph generation.

Comment: @Ben Dolman: No voodoo—it's how filling paths works. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF106 Glyphs in outline fonts are simply paths.

Comment: That seemed reasonable but I had tried NSEvenOddWindingRule whose documentation states "The direction that the path segments are drawn doesn’t affect the outcome." Just to make sure I tried it again with my original code but using NSEvenOddWindingRule and it worked! I must have had something else screwed up when I originally tested that (doh). Anyway, your explanation most certainly led me to the answer and provided an alternative solution at the same time. Thank you!